# Is there a way to count the number of columns satisfying a certain condition?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following code:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def countCol(row):
    count = 0
    for c in range(1, 7):
        if (row['D' + str(c)] < 0):
            count = count + 1
    return(count)
    
data = {'ID': random.sample(range(1, 50), 5),
        'D1': random.sample(range(-5, 5), 5),
        'D2': random.sample(range(-5, 5), 5),
        'D3': random.sample(range(-5, 5), 5),
        'D4': random.sample(range(-5, 5), 5),
        'D5': random.sample(range(-5, 5), 5),
        'D6': random.sample(range(-5, 5), 5)
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D5', 'D6'])

df['Count'] = df.apply(countCol, axis=1)
display(df)
```

From the code it is obvious, I would like to count the number of columns that have a value smaller than zero. However, the code uses a for loop and the apply function, which makes me think this is a very inefficient approach to solve this problem.

Is there be a more vectorised or faster approach?

Comment: ```df['count'] = df.lt(0).sum(axis=1)```

Comment: @sammywemmy, I think this is the proper solution if ID column is excluded.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Thanks for the observation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `DataFrame.filter` and `DataFrame.lt` to get the correct columns and get booleans back where our conditions fit, then `sum` to count the amount of columns:

```
df.filter(regex='D\d').lt(0).sum(axis=1)

0    4
1    5
2    1
3    2
4    4
dtype: int64
```

If your `ID` column is always the first one, we can use `DataFrame.iloc` instead:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:].lt(0).sum(axis=1)

0    4
1    5
2    1
3    2
4    4
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` with `lambda` like

```
df["Count"] = df.apply(lambda x: sum(x[1:] < 0) , 1)

df
   ID  D1  D2  D3  D4  D5  D6  Count
0  25   0  -3   4  -1   1   4      2
1  45   2   2  -1  -5   3   3      2
2  35   4  -4  -2   0  -4  -3      4
3  41  -3   4   3   4  -1  -1      3
4  34   3  -2   1  -4   2   1      2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to know specific columns which meet condition as well as records count, you can

```
    df2=df.apply(lambda s: s.s<0)#Boolean select less than 0
    c=df2.columns.to_numpy()#convert columns to numpy array
    df2['negcount']=[c[i] for i in df2.to_numpy()]#Using list comprehension put columns which meet set conditions in a list
    df2['count']=df2['negcount'].str.len()#Count elements in each list in each row
    df=df.join(df2.iloc[:,-2:])#join a slice of df2  back to df1
    print(df)



   ID  D1  D2  D3  D4  D5  D6              negcount  count
0  24   3   1  -5   0   4   3                  [D3]      1
1  10   1  -3   4  -1  -4   4          [D2, D4, D5]      3
2  30  -1  -1   3   4   2   1              [D1, D2]      2
3  48  -3   0  -3  -3  -2  -1  [D1, D3, D4, D5, D6]      5
4   9   4  -5  -1  -2  -5  -3  [D2, D3, D4, D5, D6]      5
```